# jQuery AJAX - status canceled

Tags: jquery, post

When i'm trying to do this request on hosting it is canceled, but it works on localhost, where is problem?

```
$(".cover_image").click(function() {
            var imgid = $(this).attr('title');
            var dataString =
                '&imgid=' + imgid;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + "welcome/cover",
                async: true,
                data: dataString,
                success: function(msg) {

                    window.location.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover='+ msg;
                    //  $("#loading").css('visibility', 'hidden');

                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loading").css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
            }).done(function () {
                    $("#loading").css('visibility', 'hidden');

                });
        });
```

Comment: I think you should check your `baseUrl`

Comment: what is baseurl? does it have the trailing slash?

Comment: var baseUrl = window.location.origin + "/";